# How can you make a "page not found" feature using Flask?

Tags: python, web, flask, jinja2

If you go to a website's sub-url that does not exist, say
http://www.reddit.com/notathing

It will take you to a custom website with flashy graphics, and easy links to get back on track.

Vanilla Flask will display

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

How can one create a "catch-all" webpage using Flask to spiff up a user error such as this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/):

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Answer (score 5):

This is described in the docs about [Error Handlers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers).  Decorating a view with `@app.errorhandler()` instead of `@app.route()` will treat it as the view for the given type of error.  In your case, a 404 handler might look like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    cool_image = pick_cool_image()
    return render_template('404_not_found.html', image=cool_image)
```

Now the 404_not_found.html template can use the cool image you picked in the handler to show an interesting page.

You can handle any error status code this way, but you can also handle Python exceptions that would otherwise cause 500 errors.  In this way you can make really detailed error pages that are specific to the type of error.  For example:

```
class NotModeratorError(Exception):
    pass

@app.errorhandler(NotModeratorError)
def not_a_moderator(e):
    return render_template('errors/not_a_moderator.html')

@app.route('/mod_powers')
def mod_powers():
    if not current_user.is_moderator:
        raise NotModeratorError()
```